# Some questions about finite abelian p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group such that $pG=\langle0\rangle$, prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_p+Z_p+...+Z_p$( direct sum of $Z_p$)

I am trying to prove that the order of $G$ is some power of $p$, then the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, we will be done.

But how to prove it? And I don't know how to use $pG=\langle 0\rangle$.

Comment: Alternatively to using the classification, note that the assumption makes the group a vector spaces over the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, I only learn vector spaces in linear algebra. I don't know how to relate it with this problem. Could you explain this problem without using vector space?

Comment: The order of $G$ is a power of $p$ by the definition of a $p$-group. Do you want to prove the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh: the standard definition of a (not necessarily finite) $p$-group is a group in which the order of every element is a power of $p$.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Oh, I don't know this definition, now I understand, thank you.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok. That wasn't the definition I was aware of. But by Cauchy's theorem, for any prime dividing the order of the group, there must be an element of that order, so this shows that both definitions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
The structure theorem for finite abelian groups says that every finite abelian group can be written as
$$\ZZ_{m_1}\times\ZZ_{m_2}\times\cdots\times\ZZ_{m_k}$$
The size of such a group is $\prod_i m_i$. If your group is a $p$ group, then of course each $m_i$ is a power of $p$. On the other hand, if there exists an $m_i$ such that $m_i = p^r$ for $r > 1$ (say $i = 1$, so that $m_1 = p^r, r> 1$), then the element $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ is not killed by $p$, contradicting your assumption that $pG = 0$.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $pG = 0$, then we can define a structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ module over $G$, and so $G$ is a vector space.

Then $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p} \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p} $$ because this is obvious in the case of vector spaces.